# Swift 2 to 3 Migration jsonObject produces 'Any' not the expected contextual result type 'AnyObject?'

Tags: json, swift, swift2, swift3, ios10

I'm attempting to convert the following code from this library (https://github.com/dankogai/swift-json) into Swift 3 Compatible code.

I'm stuck on this line though.

```
obj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(
```

**The error I get is jsonObject produces 'Any', not the expected contextual result type 'AnyObject?'**

The code before I attempted converting to swift 3 in its full context is below.

```
public convenience init(data:NSData) {
        var err:NSError?
        var obj:AnyObject?
        do {
            obj = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(
                data, options:[])
        } catch let error as NSError {
            err = error
            obj = nil
        }
        self.init(err != nil ? err! : obj!)
    }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Swift 3 `id` types are now imported as `Any` rather than `AnyObject`. You can either change the type of `obj` to `Any` or cast it to `AnyObject`.

Comment: can you give me an example what that would look like? I'm a bit rusty with casting in Swift

Comment: You should be able to just do this:  `obj = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(
                data, options:[]) as AnyObject`

Comment: I changed obj:Any? like you suggested, think I finally understand.  I then got an error on the self.init that says Result values in '?': expression have mismatching types 'JSON.NSError (aka 'NSError') and 'Any'.  No pun intended but...any ideas?

Comment: Without seeing the init's method definition, its hard to say how to fix it. The init probably takes a single `AnyObject` argument, but thats guessing.

Comment: I have done following code :- json =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject( with: data, options:[]) as AnyObject for solving above issue.